# Can the derivative of a continuous function be minus infinity?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Derivative tells us slope of a tangent . It'll be infinity when the line is vertical or we say tangent is vertical , but is minus infinity possible . What would the line look like?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You mean like $f(x)=-\sqrt x$ at $x=0$?

Comment: Take any function $f(x)$ for which you know that the derivative "is" $\infty$ (which I assume means the corresponding limit is $\infty$). Now take the function $g(x)=-f(x)$. The limit for $g(x)$ will be $-\infty$, which also represents a vertical tangent, just one that is approximated by secants of negative slope rather than secants of positive slope.